# SeekBar remove one selection

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar

I have a seekbar that goes from 0-12, but I'd like to make it not possible to select one of the values based on some other criteria.  Is that possible?  i.e. they can slide through 0-12 but it skips 5?  Is there a better selection method maybe?  I like how minimal the seekbar is to perform this function, but open to other ideas, if removing a selection is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do it

```
bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

        var previousProgress = 0
        val disabled = intArrayOf(3,5,7)

        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            if (disabled.contains(progress)) seekBar?.progress = previousProgress

        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
            previousProgress = seekBar?.progress ?: 0
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

    })
```